# Prove that there exists a number $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv 2$ (mod $p$) and $x^2 \equiv 3$ (mod $q$)

Tags: quadratic-reciprocity

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct odd primes for which $(2/p)$ and $(3/q)$ are both $1$. Prove that there exists a number $x$ such that $x^2 ≡ 2$ (mod $p$) and $x^2 ≡ 3$ (mod $q$).

This is my attempt to solve it:

$x^2=2$ (mod $p$) and $y^2=3$ (mod $q$)

$p \equiv 1$ or $7$ (mod $8$)

$q \equiv 1$ or $11$ (mod $12$)

I'm totally lost after this.

Comment: I know we have to prove that $x^2 = y^2$ but I can't figure out how to...

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem - done

Comment: To use the Chinese Remainder Theorem we would have to first assume that $x^2 = y^2$ but this is the thing we have to prove...

Comment: Think about it a little bit more, Sohail – Hagen knows whereof he writes.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't understand it could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Look at an example. Say $p=7$, $q=11$. We can take $x=3$, $y=5$. Now, what happens if $z\equiv3\bmod7$ and $z\equiv5\bmod{11}$? By the way, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry into it.

Comment: Anything to say, Sohail?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.